# Generating file structure from filenames using Google Drive API and Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have a bunch of files sat in a Google Drive folder whose filenames contains information regarding the desired folder/subfolder structure:

```
[folder~subfolder] MyFile.ext
```

Some files simply read:

```
[folder] MyOtherFile.ext
```

I am looking for a way to sort the files into the desired file structure using thr Google Drive API, creating the folders/subfolders if they do not already exist.

This is what I have so far:

```
import os
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# Set up the Drive API credentials
creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(r"CREDENTIALS_PATH", ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])

# Define the name of the Google Drive folder
folder_name = 'FOLDER_CONTAINING_FILES'

# Create a Drive API client
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

# Define the function to parse the subdirectories and sub-subdirectories
def parse_directory(filename):
    # Split the filename by '] '
    parts = filename.split('] ')
    subdirs = []
    for part in parts:
        # Check if the part is a subdirectory
        if '[' in part:
            subdir = part[1:]
            subdirs.append(subdir)
    return subdirs


# Get the list of files in the Google Drive folder
try:
    query = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false and name='" + folder_name + "'"
    folder = service.files().list(q=query).execute().get('files')[0]
    folder_id = folder.get('id')
    query = "'" + folder_id + "' in parents and trashed = false and mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
    files = service.files().list(q=query).execute().get('files')
except HttpError as error:
    print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
    files = []

# Create dictionaries to store the subdirectories and sub-subdirectories
subdirs_dict = {}
subsubdirs_dict = {}

# Loop through the files and create the subdirectories and sub-subdirectories if necessary
for file in files:
    filename = file.get('name')
    subdirs = parse_directory(filename)
    if len(subdirs) == 0:
        continue
    parent_id = folder_id
    for i in range(len(subdirs)):
        subdir = subdirs[i]
        if i == len(subdirs) - 1:
            subsubdir = ''
        else:
            subsubdir = subdirs[i+1]
        if subdir not in subdirs_dict:
            # Create the subdirectory if it doesn't exist
            metadata = {'name': subdir, 'parents': [parent_id], 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'}
            subdir_file = service.files().create(body=metadata, fields='id').execute()
            subdirs_dict[subdir] = subdir_file.get('id')
        parent_id = subdirs_dict[subdir]
        if subsubdir != '':
            if subsubdir not in subsubdirs_dict:
                # Create the sub-subdirectory if it doesn't exist
                metadata = {'name': subsubdir, 'parents': [parent_id], 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'}
                subsubdir_file = service.files().create(body=metadata, fields='id').execute()
                subsubdirs_dict[subsubdir] = subsubdir_file.get('id')
            parent_id = subsubdirs_dict[subsubdir]

# Loop through the files and move them to the appropriate subdirectory or sub-subdirectory
for file in files:
    filename = file.get('name')
    subdirs = parse_directory(filename)
    if len(subdirs) == 0:
        continue
    parent_id = folder_id
    for i in range(len(subdirs)):
        subdir = subdirs[i]
        if i == len(subdirs) - 1:
            subsubdir = ''
        else:
            subsubdir = subdirs[i+1]
        if subdir in subdirs_dict:
            parent_id = subdirs_dict[subdir]
        if subsubdir != '' and subsubdir in subsubdirs_dict:
            parent_id = subsubdirs_dict[subsubdir]
        metadata = {'name': filename, 'parents': [parent_id]}
        service.files().update(fileId=file.get('id'), body=metadata).execute()
```

At present, my code produces (almost) the correct folders but they are not nested properly. For example, for these input files:

```
[0_diss] good_journals.txt
[0_diss~historic_disses] Zhang (2020) - NAV premia.pdf
[0_diss~literature] A Guide to Writing the Literature Review.pdf
```

The script produces the following folders:

```
0_diss
0_diss~historic_disses
0_diss~literature
```

What I want is for folders entitled '0_diss', 'historic_disses', and 'literature' to be created (if they do not already exist) and for 'historic_disses' and 'literature' to be a subfolder of '0_diss'. I hope this makes more sense.

Would really appreciate some help on this one, I'm not an experienced programmer and am trying my best to learn Python. Thanks.

Comment: Please present examples of current output & expected output with given input. "Almost correct" is not helpful when describing a problem

Comment: If I understand correctly, you use the "~" character to indicate subfolders? Because in your code, you only split on "]"

Comment: @Destroy666 thanks for commenting. I've edited the original post to include current versus expected ouput – hope this helps.

Comment: @EmanuelP thanks for your comment. You are correct on both counts: if the filename is [folder~subfolder] MyFile.txt, how can I change the parsing function to extract both folder and subfolder names? Thanks.

Comment: I'll submit an answer because the question looks more or less productive now, but you should post the whole attempt next time, including the splitting of `~`. Not sure why you managed to split by `[]` but you're unable to come up with a solution for `~`. Did you try in the 1st place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes there can only be one `~` because that's the data and examples you provided. You can parse directories like this:

```
from typing import Optional
import re

def parse_directories(filename: str) -> Optional[dict]:
    dirs = {}
    
    # Make sure we have a supported file name, match anything not ]~ into group 1
    # Then optionally match anything not ] after ~ into group 2 
    match = re.search('^\[([^\]~]+)~?([^\]]+)?\]', filename)
    
    # If anything was matched, assign always available parent, else return null
    if (not match):
        return None

    dirs['parent'] = match.group(1)
    
    # If child was found, assign it too
    if (match.group(2)):
        dirs['child'] = match.group(2)
    
    return dirs
```

Then use just one loop to create new directories and move the files into them:

```
for filename in filenames:
    newdirs = parse_directories(filename)
    if newdirs:
        if 'child' in newdirs:
            # Create your child folder
            # To verify if it's been already made simply store paths as a list
        else:
            # Create newdirs['parent'] if needed
    
        # Move the file to the new/already existing folder, you don't need a 2nd loop
```

This should get you on the right track.